# With Apache's ProxyPassMatch, how do I pass on only part of my URL?

Tags: django, apache, proxypass, apache-config

I'm running Apache 2.4 with a Python 3 / Django 3 app, both in Docker containers.  If my Apache container gets a request with "/api", I would like to redirect that request to the Python container.  So if my Apache request is

```
http://localhost:9090/api/states/US
```

I would like to redirect to the Python container using the URL

```
http://web:8000/states/US
```

In my virtual host file I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName directory.example.com

    ProxyPassMatch    ^/api http://web:8000/(.*)
    ProxyPassReverse  ^/api http://web:8000/(.*)
```

But when I make the request for "http://localhost:9090/api/states/US", I get this in my Docker logs

```
maps-web-1       | Not Found: /(.*)/api/states/US
maps-apache-1    | 172.23.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2022:20:23:49 +0000] "GET /api/states/US HTTP/1.1" 404 6128
```

So evidently my ProxyPassMatch is not correct.  How do I set that up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed out quotes by the looks of it.  Try something like

```
ProxyPassMatch    "/api(.*)" "http://web:8000$1"
ProxyPassReverse  "/api(.*)" "http://web:8000$1"
```

In the above the (.*) is a curved bracket selector that finds everything after /api and places it in the $1 position in the next string.